# iPhone 6 new folders for mp3 files

Tags: ios

How do I create sub-directories for my files, pictures and mp3 files?  New to iOS and this does not seem like a user friendly OS.  There is zero interaction with Windows or Android.

Comment: Frankly, Apple neither expects nor wants you to be playing in the file structure. MP3s go in playlists. Pictures go in Photos. They are both perfectly capable of sub-foldering within the user environment. To want the freedom you have in Android is to also have the 'luxury' of needing to choose a good antivirus...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://readdle.com/products/documents). I use *Documents (by Readdle)* that works fine and it's free.

You can get files from your computer, sync with Dropbox, iCloud, other cloud services and any source you can imagine. You can also download files from the Web using built-in browser. Organize the files into folders for your convenience using the brand new file manager. 
You can manage different file formats and also read and modify PDFs. You can also create folders, according to the different contents.

Obviously, you will never have Android performance (system specs are very different) but I think this app can be a good compromise.

You can easily download the app for your iPhone following [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4).